# GithubからダウンロードしたprjのコンパイルがXcodeで通りません。

Tags: xcode

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
開発者アカウントを作成せずpersonal teamでgithubからダウンロードしたサンプルを実行しようとしたところ以下のエラーが出ています。

```
None of your accounts are a member of '省略':  An unexpected error occurred. Xcode cannot find a team matching '省略'.
No profiles for 'サンプルプロジェクト名' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'サンプルプロジェクト名'.
Code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'
```

`signing->Automatically manage signing` をONにすると`Signing for "サンプルプロジェクト" requires a development team.`

と出るので、開発ライセンスが必要なのかな？と考えていますがいかがでしょうか。
なるべくお金をかけずに解決したいのですが。。。
お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

環境：Xcode：8.1、OS:OS X El Capitan

Comment: 何故編集を却下したのでしょうか…？ (ただ自分が別の編集をしたいだけかもしれませんが、確認ということで)少し読みにくいと思い編集しました。

Comment: エラーメッセージ部分にも編集がかかってしまったので、またXcodeのバージョンとOS情報を付加しています。